# Does $\mathbb P\{X\in A, Y\in B\}$ mean $\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ two randoms variables on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. Now, let consider $(X,Y)$ on $(\Omega ^2, \mathcal F^2, \mathbb P\times \mathbb P)$. I am a bit confuse with $\mathbb P\times \mathbb P=:\mathbb P_2$. Now, I always thought that $\mathbb P_2\{X\in A, Y\in B\}$ was to denote $\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})$. But $\{X\in A, Y\in B\}\in \mathcal F^2$, whereas $\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\}$ is in $\mathcal F$, no ? So I'm a bit confuse with this.

Comment: $\mathbb P\{X\in A, Y\in B\}$ mean $\mathbb P_2\{(\omega ,\omega ')\in \Omega ^2\mid X(\omega )\in A, Y(\omega ')\in B\}$.

Comment: So, there is a difference between $\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B )\})$ and $\mathbb P_2\{X\in A, Y\in B\}$ ? I thought $\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})$ was to denote $\mathbb P_2\{X\in A, Y\in B\}$, no ?

Comment: Note that $X$ and $Y$ are defined on $\Omega$. Here they are implicitly extended on $\Omega^2$ using $X(\omega, \omega') = X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega, \omega') = Y(\omega')$, I guess...

Comment: $\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})$ is not the same as $\mathbb P_2(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})$ (notice that if $\{X\in A\}\in \mathcal F$, then $\mathbb P_2\{X\in A\}=0$). In $\mathbb P_2(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})$, the event $\{X\in A\}$ means $\{(\omega ,\omega ')\in \Omega ^2\mid X(\omega )\in A, Y(\omega' )\in \Omega \}$.

Comment: ok... strange... but when $X$ and $Y$ are indepedent, do we have $\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}\mathbb P\{Y\in B\}$ or $\mathbb P_2(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\})=\mathbb P_2\{X\in A\}\mathbb P_2\{Y\in B\}$ ?

Comment: @sam : both hold since $\mathbb P_2\{X\in A\}=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}$.

Comment: You are correct.  But I think it is better to say $\mathbb P(X \in A, y \in B)$ means $\mathbb P(X \in A\text { and }y \in B)$.  The argument inside $\mathbb P$ is thought of as an **event** not as a **set**.  (It is true that nowadays mathematicians normally use Kolmgorov's model for probability in which events are identified as sets.)

Comment: @Stockfish : not really... in fact it's $(X,Y)(\omega ,\omega ')=(X(\omega ), Y(\omega '))$ (becaus $X$ and $Y$ are on $\Omega $ not $\Omega ^2$).

Comment: @Stockfish The functions are not extended. Both remain functions on $\Omega$ but together they *induce* a function on $\Omega^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are random variables on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ then $(X,Y)$ is a notation for the function $\Omega\to\mathbb R^2$ that is prescribed by:$$\omega\mapsto(X(\omega),Y(\omega))$$

In that context $\{X\in A,Y\in B\}$ is a notation for the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in A\wedge Y(\omega)\in B\}$.

It is linked with the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have a common codomain.

Further $\mathbb P(X\in A,Y\in B)$ is an abbreviation of $\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in A\wedge Y(\omega)\in B\})$.

---

But next to that $X$ and $Y$ also induce a function $\Omega^2\to\mathbb R^2$ by:$$(\omega,\omega')\mapsto(X(\omega),Y(\omega'))$$for which I would rather use the notation $X\times Y$.

In that context we have sets like $\{X\times Y\in C\}\subseteq\Omega^2$ where $C\subseteq\mathbb R^2$.

The special case where $C=A\times B$ then causes mainly the confusion because we are tempted to write: $$\{X\times Y\in A\times B\}=\{X\in A,Y\in B\}$$

---

There is even more, since $X,Y$ also have a common domain, leading to a function: $$\Omega\sqcup\Omega=\Omega\times\{1\}\cup\Omega\times\{2\}\to \mathbb R$$

A notation for it is $[X,Y]$ and the function is prescribed by $(\omega,1)\mapsto X(\omega)$ and $(\omega,2)\mapsto Y(\omega)$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in probability theory
$$
\mathbb{P}(A,B,C,\dots) 
$$
traditionally means the same as 
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C\cap\cdots).
$$

There are also some other traditional conventions: using 
$\{X \in A\} $ for $\{\omega\in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \in A\}$, $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)$ for $\mathbb{P}(\{X\in A\})$ etc.